# Copy and Pasting Multiple cells Error 450

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy multiple cells to a new worksheet based on certain conditions.

But I am getting an error saying :

> "Wrong no. of arguments or invalid property assignment"

```
Sub sort()

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("3rd and 4th Floor Columns", "3rd Floor Beams", "Test1", "Test2"))


For k = 12 To 360
With ws(1)
i = 1
j = 1
 Select Case ws(1).Cells(k, 9).Value

 Case 26

 ws(1).Range(.Cells(k, 9), .Cells(k, 12)).Copy
 ws(3).Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 4)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 i = i + 1

 Case 57

 ws(1).Range(.Cells(k, 9), .Cells(k, 12)).Copy
 ws(4).Range(.Cells(j, 1), .Cells(j, 4)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'Application defined.. error

 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 j = j + 1

Case Else

End Select
End With
Next k
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to input the **top left cell** and the **bottom right cell** to **define a range**, so your code will look like this :

```
For k = 12 To 360
With ws(1)
    i = 1
    j = 1
    Select Case .Cells(k, 9).Value
        Case 26
            ws(1).Range(.Cells(k, 9), .Cells(k, 12)).Copy
            ws(3).Range(ws(3).Cells(i, 1)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            i = i + 1
        Case 57
            ws(1).Range(.Cells(k, 9), .Cells(k, 12)).Copy
            ws(4).Range(ws(4).Cells(j, 1)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            j = j + 1
        Case Else
    End Select
End With
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the information. I've updated the code, but now I am getting an "Application defined or Object defined" error

Comment: Hello, I've updated my question as per the new error.

Comment: My bad, it was a silly error with the use of `With`, there was reference of `ws(1)` in the ranges of `ws(3)` and `ws(4)`, see the edit! ;)

Comment: Still getting the same error :/ Run-time error 1004: Application Define or object defined error.

Comment: Damn... Are your sheets visible (not hidden in any way)? Do you have errors in the range you want to copy?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86597/discussion-between-dhruva-04-and-r3uk).

Comment: Hey I got the solution. I just changed ws(4).range(ws(4).cells()) to ws(4).cells()